# Why are there complex numbers in the exact solution of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^4+1}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Knowing that
\begin{align} 
\cot(z)=\frac{1}{z}-2z\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{\pi^2n^2-z^2} 
\end{align}
we can easily calculate the value of
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2+1}
\end{align}
by just plugging in $z=i\pi$. Therefore:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\pi \coth(\pi)-1\right)
\end{align}
In this case, the "$i's$" cancel eachother out nicely. 
I also wanted to calculate the exact value of
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^4+1}
\end{align}
with an equal approach. After partial fraction decomposition:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^4+1}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2-i}-\dfrac{1}{n^2+i}\right)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2-i}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2+i}\right)
\end{align}
By plugging in $z=\sqrt{i}\pi$ and $z=i\sqrt{i}\pi$, I arrive at:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2i}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2-i}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2+i}\right]&=\frac{1}{2i}\left[\frac{1}{2i}-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{i}} \cdot \cot(\sqrt{i}\pi)-\left(-\frac{1}{2i}-\frac{1}{2i\sqrt{i}}\cdot \cot(i\sqrt{i}\pi)\right)\right]=\\&=\frac{1}{4}\left[-2+\pi\sqrt{i}\cot(\sqrt{i}\pi)-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{i}}\cot(i\sqrt{i}\pi)\right]
\end{align}
In this case I can't get completely rid of the "$i's$" and the exact value of
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^4+1}
\end{align}
is a complex number. But the answer must obviously be a real number.
Wolfram Alpha gets:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^4+1}\approx0.57848+0.\times10^{-22}\,i
\end{align}
You now can argument that the imaginary part is negligible and so the value is a real number, but that doesn't satisfy my question, because there always will be a imaginary part in the answer.
If anyone can explain to me, why it is the case, that the exact value for
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^4+1}
\end{align}
is a complex number, I would be very glad.

Comment: The value in question is not a (non-real) complex number; it is a sum of real numbers, and hence is real. (Or infinite, in a sort of "extended reals" sense, but the sum obviously converges so this is a nonissue.) The simple reason then being that, in the method you used, presumably all of the imaginary components cancel out somehow. (This shouldn't be surprising, as similar things pop-up all throughout math; see the cubic formula and its disappearing $i$'s, or Binet's Fibonacci formula and its disappearing radicals.)

Comment: Where WolframAlpha's answer is concerned, it is probably just approximating via some method and there are some rounding errors involved. Whenever Wolfram returns an answer like that, it's reasonable to assume it really meant $0i$.

Comment: @Somos I think what the original poster had in mind was that you could somehow simplify the expression to not have imaginary components, in the same way that $(1+i)(1-i)$ can be simplified to no imaginary parts and how for certain values of $a,b,c,d$ the cubic formula can be simplified to not contain imaginary parts. For the OP, you could try converting $\cot$ to the exponential function and see if things cancel

Comment: One easy way to check your answer is a real number is to replace all instances of $i$ with a $-i$ and see it equals your original expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Addendum to Somos' answer: by expanding $\cot(x+iy)$ via trig identities, one can determine the real and imaginary parts of $\cot(z)$, allowing the answer to be expressed purely in terms of real-valued terms:

$$-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi  \sin \left(\sqrt{2} \pi \right)}{2 \sqrt{2} \left(\cos
   \left(\sqrt{2} \pi \right)-\cosh \left(\sqrt{2} \pi \right)\right)}-\frac{\pi  \sinh
   \left(\sqrt{2} \pi \right)}{2 \sqrt{2} \left(\cos \left(\sqrt{2} \pi \right)-\cosh
   \left(\sqrt{2} \pi \right)\right)}$$

Cleaning up the result a bit, with $u = \sqrt{2}\pi$ this can be written as:
$$-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\frac{\sin(u)+\sinh(u)}{\cosh(u)-\cos(u)}$$

Comment: Nice! I did not take this explicit approach, but it is good to know!

Comment: Wow thank you very much, now it is clear to me. Thank you sir

Answer (score 3):

Define $t=\pi\sqrt{i}$ and $f(z):=z\cot(z)$.
Now $f(-z)=f(z)$ for all $z$ so $f(z)=g(z^2).$

Your result is
$$ S:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4+1} = \frac14\big[-2+f(t)+f(it)\big]
 = -1/2 + (g(i\pi^2)+g(-i\pi^2))/4.$$
Rewrite this as $ S = -1/2 + \Re g(i\pi^2)/2 \approx 0.57848 $ where
$\Re z$ is the real part of $z$.